# Im trying to test my forms in my flask app using unittest, Am I doing the right way?

Tags: python, html, flask, psycopg2, python-unittest

I wanna test my app using the unittest package. specifically I'm trying to test my forms. I'm having a hard time testing the post request on how to get the data from my forms and posting it

my reference:
https://realpython.com/python-testing/#more-advanced-testing-scenarios

my test.py code

```
from app import app
import unittest

class FlaskTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_add(self):
        tester = app.test_client(self)
        response = tester.post('/Search/add', data=dict(fn = 
                 "Emmanuel Ever", ln = "Telewik", email = 
                 "everlopeztelewik@gmail.com", phone = 0912312311,  
                  address = "ILIGAN"),
    follow_redirect = True
        )
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

the function I'm going to test in app.py

```
@app.route("/Search/add", methods=['POST'])
def new():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        fn = request.form['fn']
        ln = request.form['ln']
        email = request.form['email']
        phone = request.form['phone']
        address = request.form['address']
        conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname = 'test_db3' user = 'postgres' 
           password = 'shizzle7' host = 'localhost' port = '5432'")
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("INSERT into user2 values(Default, %s, %s, %s, %s, 
        %s)",(fn,ln,email,phone,address))
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
    return redirect('/Search')
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Comment: It is not enough to just test status_code, content should be test too.

Comment: How is it done?

Comment: I usually do someting like this: `self.assertIn('xxx', response.content)`

Comment: In addition, I would test it by feeding it some invalid input and making sure that returns with the correct error message and 500 status code